# Why is my modal only taking the first prop passed to it? (Using React and Bootstrap)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using `Bootstrap` to make an `Offcanvas` component that can render a modal for each item in an array passed to it. 
However, when clicking open my modals, they each display only the first item's props. I am not sure why but how can I fix it?

I recreated a `Sandbox` demo here: [Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-carson-fgh926?file=/src/styles.css)

**If I can improve my question let me know kindly, please.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have done is not the correct way of building Modal in React .
However just to give you clarity about the mistake you have done:

The `prop` `letter` is passed correctly. The problem is the way you're calling the modal.

If you see your code in `Example.js` , you have used `data-bs-target="#exampleModal"`. And `id="exampleModal"` for the modal to show up.
So all the handlers are pointing to `exampleModal` id . Hence After you click on the buttons only the first modal shows up.

To solve this , you need to assign the  `data-bs-target` and `id` dynamically. Something like below :

```
  <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target={`#exampleModal${props.letter}`}
      >
        click to view prop
      </button>
```

and then in Modal set `id` as :

```
<div
        class="modal fade"
        id={`exampleModal${props.letter}`}
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
```

It should work as expected.

here is the working example :   [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-field-qjq7d9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much